# Azure Web App: Why is premium cheaper than standard

Tags: azure-web-app-service

Below is a suggestions on scaling up my Azure Web App, Azure gives me.

I don't really understand, why Premium is cheaper than Standard, if it has more ACU, as well as the premium benefits. The machines are currently nearly idle, but I dont think this makes a differnece in that calculation.

```
S2
200 total ACU
3.5 GB memory
A-Series compute equivalent
116.97 EUR/Month (Estimated)

P1V2
210 total ACU
3.5 GB memory
Dv2-Series compute equivalent
70.80 EUR/Month (Estimated)

S3
400 total ACU
7 GB memory
A-Series compute equivalent
233.93 EUR/Month (Estimated)

P2V2
420 total ACU
7 GB memory
Dv2-Series compute equivalent
142.21 EUR/Month (Estimated)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Under normal circumstances, [the price of scale up my Azure Web App can be calculated](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/).**

On calculator（P2V3）.

[image]

On portal(P2V3).

[image]

On calculator（S3）.

[image]

## The price calculated through the Azure Calculator should not appear as you said, but the actual price is related to the subscription, so the benefits you enjoy will be different.

My subscription is not pay as you go type, so there will be different degrees of discount. Under normal circumstances, prices are calculated through the azure calculator. The actual payment is based on the price you see on the portal (may be related to subscription, enjoy different discounts).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check that. Do you know by any chance, if discounts are transparent and can be seen somewhere in the portal?

Comment: @stena [Subscription 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKSDe.png) and  [Subscription 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0skxv.png). So I guess it has something to do with subscription.

Comment: @stena Stackoverflow is generally used to answer technical questions. Regarding pricing questions, you can [raise a billing support ticket on the portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WocxG.png).